# In Java, what is the fastest way to get the system time?

Tags: java, time, calendar

I'm developing a system that often use the system time because the `Delayed` interface.

What is fastet way to get the time from system?

Currently I'm using `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()` every time I need to get the time, but I don't know if there is a faster way.

Comment: where do you use the time millis with DelayQueue?

Comment: I was not clear, I only use in the class that implements the Delayed interface in the `getDelay()` method.

Comment: @Renato, Calendar.getInstance() and new Date() both use System.currentTimeMillis() however Calendar is by far the slowest.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)
*"Returns the current time in milliseconds"*.
**Use this to get the actual system time.**

[`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29).
*"The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time"*
**Use this is you're measuring time lapses / events.**

Comment: Note that the two methods have different characteristics and you should choose the one suitable for what you need it for.

Comment: As far as I know, DelayQueue uses TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS uses to make the calculations of time, so maybe `System.nanoTime()` is more suitable in this case to avoid having to convert to the unit in getDelay()` method.

Comment: You can use any unit there, so either works. nanoTime is more precise

Comment: Has anyone run any benchmark tests or have some analytical evidence that System.currentTimeMillis() is faster than Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()?

Comment: Even if it is not, you should not create a new instance to get the millis, when you can just get them from System :)

Comment: any idea what said "fixed but arbitrary" origin is (in most implementations)?

Answer (score 5):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is fastest as per below test case

```
public class ClassTest
{
    @Test
    public void testSystemCurrentTime()
    {
        final Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_00_000; i++)
        {
            System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        stopwatch.stop();
        System.out.println("System.currentTimeMillis(): " + stopwatch);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDateTime()
    {
        final Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_00_000; i++)
        {
            (new Date()).getTime();
        }
        stopwatch.stop();
        System.out.println("(new Date()).getTime(): " + stopwatch);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCalendarTime()
    {
        final Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_00_000; i++)
        {
            Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        }
        stopwatch.stop();
        System.out.println("Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): " + stopwatch);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInstantNow()
    {
        final Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_00_000; i++)
        {
            Instant.now();
        }
        stopwatch.stop();
        System.out.println("Instant.now(): " + stopwatch);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(new Date()).getTime(): 36.89 ms
Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): 448.0 ms
Instant.now(): 34.13 ms
System.currentTimeMillis(): 10.28 ms
```

**But**,

`Instant.now()` is fast + simpler and provides other utility as well like `Instant.now().getEpochSecond();`,`Instant.now().getNano();`, `Instant.now().compareTo(otherInstant);` and many more.

Comment: This is the recommended way for 99.9 % of purposes. It may not be strictly the fastest (I made no measurements), but clarity is king, not speed.

Comment: @craigcaulfield I wonder why this doesn't provide an answer to the question.His answer just needs some details to declare why it is fastest.

Comment: Exactly I gave my suggestion on that and will provide the stats.

Answer (score 4):

In short answer, `System.currentTimeMillis()` is faster.

```
@Test
public void testSystemCurrentTime() {
    final Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1_00_000; i++) {
        System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    stopwatch.stop();
    System.out.println("System.currentTimeMillis(): " + stopwatch);
}

@Test
public void testDateTime() {
    final Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1_00_000; i++) {
        (new Date()).getTime();
    }
    stopwatch.stop();
    System.out.println("(new Date()).getTime(): " + stopwatch);
}

@Test
public void testCalendarTime() {
    final Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1_00_000; i++) {
        Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    }
    stopwatch.stop();
    System.out.println("Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): " + stopwatch);
}
```

I ran above test cases and I found following result:

```
System.currentTimeMillis(): 5.208 ms    (new Date()).getTime(): 19.57 ms    Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): 148.2 ms
System.currentTimeMillis(): 4.685 ms    (new Date()).getTime(): 11.53 ms    Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): 122.6 ms
System.currentTimeMillis(): 4.734 ms    (new Date()).getTime(): 11.66 ms    Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): 131.5 ms
System.currentTimeMillis(): 4.018 ms    (new Date()).getTime(): 19.33 ms    Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): 127.6 ms
System.currentTimeMillis(): 5.474 ms    (new Date()).getTime(): 16.74 ms    Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): 113.6 ms
System.currentTimeMillis(): 3.871 ms    (new Date()).getTime(): 14.46 ms    Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): 120.5 ms
System.currentTimeMillis(): 8.223 ms    (new Date()).getTime(): 11.65 ms    Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): 173.8 ms
System.currentTimeMillis(): 4.611 ms    (new Date()).getTime(): 9.978 ms    Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): 117.9 ms
System.currentTimeMillis(): 3.794 ms    (new Date()).getTime(): 11.33 ms    Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): 89.79 ms
System.currentTimeMillis(): 4.298 ms    (new Date()).getTime(): 12.37 ms    Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(): 123.8 ms
```

I hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

For large request number, I believe there should be a Thread in charge of update the current system time avoing each thread doing it independently.

Comment: True but all the operating systems I have seen tend to do that for you

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` probably.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.currentTimeMillis
```

is the simple answer

Answer (score 0):

`long timeMilliSec = System.currentTimeMillis();`