# Most efficient way to round a timestamp to the nearest 10 seconds

Tags: java

What is the most efficient way in Java (11) to round a given timestamp (e.g. System.currentTimeMillis()) to the nearest 10 seconds?

e.g. 12:55:11 would be 12:55:10 and 12:55:16 would be 12:55:20

This code is executed ~10-20 times per second, so it must be efficient.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You need to define efficient. 10-20 times a second is not all that much to a computer. Games render entire 3D scenes with millions or even billions of polygons 60 times a second.

Comment: fair.. ;)
with efficient, I meant as efficient as possible. (As in if I can avoid any overhead, I'd like to)

Comment: How is rounding a time stamp different from rounding a number? A timestamp is a number, so you would round to 10000 ms.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552575/in-java-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-the-system-time suggests that your method is more computationally efficient than other typical ways of getting the current time, except using the `Instant` class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably this:

```
 long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
 long roundedTime = (time + 5_000) / 10_000 * 10_000;
```

Basically 3 x 64 bit primitive arithmetic operations.

<sup>(If you want to truncate to 10 seconds granularity, just remove the `+ 5_000`.)</sup>

Theoretically we should consider integer overflow.  In practice the above code should be OK for roughly the next 292 million years.  (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).)

Comment: if I run into issues after 292 million years, I'll contact you again. Thanks ;)

Comment: actually, can you help me understanding this? I'm not getting it. you're adding 5 seconds, then you divide and multiply by 10 secs. I might have a blocker in my head, but divding by 10k and then multiplying by 10 should be the same afterwards no?

Comment: Unlike VB, JS or Python, in Java (and C++, etc) a `long` division yields a `long` result, so there is no fraction.

Comment: Remember we are doing Java integer division.  That discards the fractional part so that the result is an integer.  So dividing by 10_000 and multiplying by 10_000 truncates to 10 seconds.  By adding 5_000 we are causing the computation to round rather than truncate.  14 seconds -> 10 and 15 seconds -> 20.

Comment: This is so impressively clever that for the first time in forever I'm going to upvote a question which asks for the "most efficient", something which is usually impossible to prove. But this seems like a very reasonable assumption.